# Spring boot RestAPI Always return 404 Not Found Error

Tags: java, spring, post, http-status-code-404

I was made RESTAPI for send otp numbers to given emails, it's return always 404 error message with bellow response,

```
{
  "timestamp": "2024-02-12T11:50:31.545+00:00",
  "status": 404,
  "error": "Not Found",
  "path": "/api/v1/otp/sendOTP"
}
```

[image]

And I add my `OTPController` class bellow,

```
package com.example.chatappAPI10.Controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.chatappAPI10.DTO.OTPDetails;
import com.example.chatappAPI10.Service.SendOTPNumber;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "api/v1/otp")
public class OTPController {
    @Autowired
    private SendOTPNumber sendOTPNumber;
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @PostMapping(value = "/sendOTP")
    public ResponseEntity sendOTP(@RequestBody OTPDetails otpDetails) {
        System.out.println("otpDetails.getToMail()");
        return sendOTPNumber.sendOTPNumber();
    }

}
```

Also bellow I add my `SendOTPNumber` class,

```
package com.example.chatappAPI10.Service;

import java.util.Random;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.example.chatappAPI10.DTO.OTPDetails;
import com.example.chatappAPI10.DTO.ResponseDTO;
@Service
public class SendOTPNumber {
    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;
    @Autowired
    private ResponseDTO responseDTO;
    @Autowired
    private OTPDetails otpDetails;

    private void setRandomOTP() {
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNumber = random.nextInt(9000) + 1000;
        otpDetails.setOtpNumber(String.valueOf(randomNumber));
    }

    private void setFromEmail() {
        otpDetails.setFromEmail("ketawalagedhanusha@gmail.com");
    }

    private void setSubject() {
        String subjectOfEmail = "Hello Chat up! OTP verification";
        otpDetails.setMailSubject(subjectOfEmail);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public ResponseEntity sendOTPNumber() {
        try {
            SimpleMailMessage otSimpleMailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
            setFromEmail();
            setRandomOTP();
            setSubject();
            otSimpleMailMessage.setFrom(otpDetails.getFromEmail());
            otSimpleMailMessage.setSubject(otpDetails.getMailSubject());
            otSimpleMailMessage.setText(otpDetails.getOtpNumber());
            otSimpleMailMessage.setTo(otpDetails.getToMail());
            javaMailSender.send(otSimpleMailMessage);
            responseDTO.setCode("200");
            responseDTO.setMessage("Success");
            responseDTO.setOtpNumber(otpDetails.getOtpNumber());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(responseDTO, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            responseDTO.setCode("404");
            responseDTO.setMessage(e.getMessage());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(responseDTO, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not add my DTO class because I thought those are not important with this issue,
and I try many options in stackoverflow regarding with this issue all are not fix my issue, I addded those solutions bellow,

[I was tried this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31318107/20521312)

[I was tried this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72456252/20521312)

Comment: What does your `@SpringBootAPplication` annotated class look like? It doesn't make sense to autowire `ResponseDTO` and `OTPDetails`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a slash "/" to you request mapping. It should look like this: /api/v1/otp.